# Can i fetch multiple API and set states between api calls? (React and axios)

Tags: reactjs, api, axios

I want to fetch api and set state, then fetch another api with the state that comes from first one. So is that possible ?

Here is my code that i struggle with ;

```
 useEffect(()=>{

    const fetchPokemonSpecies =  async (pokemon) => {

        const data = await axios("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-species/"+pokeName).then( (response) => 
         axios(response.data.evolution_chain.url)).then((response) => {setPokemonFirstEvolution(response.data.chain.evolves_to[0].species.name)
        setPokemonFirstForm(response.data.chain.species.name)

        setPokemonSecondEvolution(response.data.chain.evolves_to[0].evolves_to[0].species.name)})
        setPokemonSpecies(data)
        setPokemonCategory(data.genera[7].genus)

    }
```

Thanks already !

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but why do you need to do it explicitly with the set state? If you have the data why not use it directly?

Comment: Cause also i want to render the data from the first one. I solve it with 2 different api calls but still wondering if i could make it with state

Answer (score 0):

So i just solve my problem this way ;

```
     const [pokemonCategory, setPokemonCategory] = useState([])
    const [pokemonSecondEvolution, setPokemonSecondEvolution] = useState([])
    const [pokemonFirstEvolution, setPokemonFirstEvolution] = useState([])
   const [pokemonFirstForm, setPokemonFirstForm] = useState([])
   const [pokemonFirstFormIcon, setPokemonFirstFormIcon] = useState([])
   const [pokemonFirstEvoIcon, setPokemonFirstEvoIcon] = useState([])
  const [pokemonSecondEvoIcon, setPokemonSecondFormIcon] = useState([])
 
    useEffect(()=>{
        const fetchPokemonSpecies =  async (pokemon) => {
            const data = await axios("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-species/"+pokeName).then( (response) => response.data)
            setPokemonSpecies(data)
            setPokemonCategory(data.genera[7].genus)

            const data2 = await axios(data.evolution_chain.url).then((response) => axios("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/"+response.data.chain.evolves_to[0].species.name))

            setPokemonFirstEvoIcon(data2.data.sprites.other.dream_world.front_default)
            const data3 = await axios(data.evolution_chain.url).then((response) => axios("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/"+response.data.chain.evolves_to[0].evolves_to[0].species.name))
            setPokemonSecondFormIcon(data3.data.sprites.other.dream_world.front_default)

            const data4 = await axios(data.evolution_chain.url).then((response) => axios("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/"+response.data.chain.species.name))
            setPokemonFirstFormIcon(data4.data.sprites.other.dream_world.front_default)
            
        } 
    fetchPokemonSpecies()
   
    },[])
    useEffect(()=>{
    const fetchPokemonEvoChain =  async (pokemon) => {
        const data = await axios("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-species/"+pokeName).then( (response) => 
         axios(response.data.evolution_chain.url)).then((response) => {setPokemonFirstEvolution(response.data.chain.evolves_to[0].species.name)
        setPokemonFirstForm(response.data.chain.species.name)
        setPokemonSecondEvolution(response.data.chain.evolves_to[0].evolves_to[0].species.name)})

    } 
fetchPokemonEvoChain()

},[])
```

idk if it is the optimal way but it works